# Extending methods in Javascript classes

Tags: javascript, icefaces, prototypejs, icefaces-1.8

I'm ("still", for those who read my previous posts) working on an ICEFaces web application.

#### This question can be interpreted as general Javascript question, so read on if you don't know much about ICEFaces

I need to extend the behaviour of the classes created by ICEFaces Javascript framework, in particular `ToolTipPanelPopup`.

I cannot modify the source code of the library (otherwise I would have achieved my goal).
This is how ICEFaces defines the class (much like jQuery and other Javascript frameworks).

```
ToolTipPanelPopup = Class.create({
   [...]
  showPopup: function() {
    [...]
  },


  updateCordinate: function(event) {
     [...]
  },

    [...]
});
```

My question is very simple

### How do I extend the behaviour of `showPopup()` function in order to run my custom function at the end of it?

I mean something like following Java example code that supposes inheritance

```
public void ShowPopup()
{
    super.ShowPopup();
    customMethod();
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on Prototype (hence this is not an answer), but I *think* that that is what $super is for in Prototype. I *think* you can use your code above with '$super' for 'super'.

Comment: I may have an answer that fits your question. Would you mind to put a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example which I can use for experiments? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var original = ToolTipPanel.showPopup;
ToolTipPanel.showPopup = function() {
   original();  //this is kind of like the call to super.showPopup()
   //your code
};
```

I tried out this trivial example in Firebug, and it seems to work:

```
var obj = {
   func: function() { 
     console.log("foo"); 
   }
};

obj.func();

var original = obj.func;
obj.func = function() {
   original();
   console.log("bar");
};

obj.func();
```

Firebug output:

```
foo
foo
bar
```

So what's happening here is that you're saving a reference to the original `showPopup` function. Then you're creating a closure and assigning it back to `showPopup`. The original `showPopup` is not lost, because you still have a reference to it in `original`. In the closure, you call the function that `original` references, and then you have your own code. Just swap around the order if you want to do something first *before* you call `original`. Since you're using a closure, `original` is lexically bound to the current scope and should be available every time the new `showPopup` is called (if I'm wrong about this, someone please correct me).

Let me know if this works out for you.

Comment: +1 for the correctness of the general-purpose problem. Now, my problem is that in my current working environment the ToolTipPanelPopup class is not visible (but I'm still able to open ICE popups). I'll investigate and remember your advice

Comment: @djechelon what is the mechanism you use to open popups currently? I'm not that familiar with ICEFaces :)

Comment: I first declare an <ice:panelPopup filled with contents on my JSPX markup, and bind its rendered property to a backing bean's property. When an action needs to trigger the popup's opening, I just set the value in the backing bean accordingly. I think that Javascript code is triggered when the popup is rendered, and then I can remap keyboard in order to have ESC do cancel and ENTER do ok in a modal yes/no box (obviously resetting keyboard mappings when popup is closed).

Comment: @djechelon I wonder if you could wrap that component with a custom component? You could then override the function after the page has loaded (put a handler on window.onload).

Comment: If you mean editing ICEFaces source code and redistribute it the simple answer is that I can't. We must use vanilla libraries

Comment: @djechelon I'm not sure how ICEFaces work, but isn't it possible to create custom components (sort of like tags?). If so, you could create a custom component that wraps around the existing component.

Comment: That's seriously feasible, however there is lots of existing code in our codebase and we just have been reported an issue that I THINK can be fixed by patching the Javascript. The problem is that while your answer is correct it seems that ICEFaces is not invoking that functions when opening modal tooltips. I'm finding another way

Comment: @djechelon That sucks :( Good luck either way :)